# why shouldnt we use own threads in Jboss?

Tags: java, jboss

Why we should not use own threads in JBoss?
In many places i have seen that using own threads is not recommended
Why?
Its also advised to use WorkManagers.
How using workmanagers solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, you shouldn't acquire *any* unmanaged resources in an application deployed into a container. The main reason is that the container must be able to manage the lifecycle of your application: start it, stop it, uninistall it, etc. If you start your own threads, the container will not be able to stop them when it wants to stop your application and thread leak will ensue. The same is true for all other resources.

BTW nonconformance to these rules is the number one reason why Java EE containers have to be restarted every once a while. It is not their implementation's fault, but the deployed applications'.

Comment: Thanks , how work managers will be useful in this context and what they actually are?